# Ряд однородных (или неоднородных) определений

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые при перечислении этих определений?

Поэтому энергетические войны следует рассматривать в контексте глобальной исторической проектной, мироустроительной борьбы между противодействующими социальными субъектами.

Comment: Хоть примерно что это такое — проектная мироустроительная борьба? А социальный субъект? Именно в контексте глобальной исторической?

Comment: Если бы я понимала этот текст до конца... Суть его в том, что идет война между странами за энергоресурсы и за контроль над ними. И что в этом справедливо, а что - нет.
___

Очевидно, проектная мироустроительная война - это война, которая имеет своим проектом какое-либо новое устройство мира, выгодное ей.

Comment: Но так никто не говорит. Потому что (патамушта) любая война подходит под это определение.

Э-э, кстати, кому это "ей"? Войне?! )))

Comment: Выгодное государству - я, естественно, имела в виду.  Нет. Есть война, чтобы оторвать кусок, завоевать территорию, и есть войны за устройство мира в целом.

Answer (score 2):

Это неоднородные определения, запятых нет вообще. Речь идёт о глобальной (охватывающей весь мир) исторической (в разрезе общей истории) проектной (охватывающей государства, устроенные по разным проектам - буржуазные, империалистические, социалистические по коммунистическому проекту, исламистские, католицистские и т.д.) мироустроительной (стремящейся к развитию и мирному взаимодействию разных систем с разным устройством) борьбе. Попробуйте разобраться здесь:
http://www.dslib.net/polit-instituty/institucionalnye-aspekty-globalnogo-upravlenija-politicheskimi-processami.html.

Comment: Целых четыре неоднородных определения подряд – многовато...

Comment: Тогда попробуйте поставить союз И между какими-то из них(ведь однородные члены соединены сочинительной связью) - получится глупость:глобальной исторической,и проектной, и мироустроительной борьбы.Это разные качества борьбы.Вернее, характеризуют её с разных сторон.

Comment: А насчёт четырёх подряд - всяко бывает. "Алеша подал ему маленькое складное круглое белое зеркальце." - тоже 4.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить вариант, который хотя бы можно прочесть:

"Поэтому энергетические войны следует рассматривать в контексте глобальной исторической, проектной, мироустроительной борьбы между противодействующими социальными субъектами".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

А.  Общий принцип

1) К сожалению, тема однородных/неоднородных определений  до сих пор рассматривается формально, только  с учетом смыслового значения  отдельных слов.  Потом это понимание механически переносится  в любое предложение, в любой текст.

2) К примеру, заданное предложение  соотносится с «классикой» неоднородных определений: "Алеша подаал ему (ПЗ) маленькое складное круглое белое зеркальце». Рядом с церковью (ПЗ) стояла высокая узкая деревянная колокольня. 
Семантика этих определений вполне понятна,  не зависит от контекста, а структура предложений, включающая короткие прилагательные, такова, что из них без труда можно составить две фразы (тема – рема). Это читаемые варианты.

3) А вот примеры более сложных сочетаний, где для однородных прилагательных используется перечислительная интонация:  В сундуке я нашел пожелтевшую, написанную по-латыни гетманскую грамоту. Она несла отвратительные, тревожные жёлтые цветы. Петя был теперь красивый, румяный пятнадцатилетний мальчик. Стояли жаркие, безветренные июльские дни. Перед ним был типичный добрый, простодушный русский человек.

Б. А теперь вернемся к заданному предложению.

1) «Глобальный и исторический» – отношения  неоднородные и понятные по смыслу, но и они в конкретном тексте могут быть сближены по значению и стать однородными: глобальные – это важные для истории.

2) Семантика слова "проектный", скорее, авторская (от проект - план, замысел, намерение), но можно считать, что «проектная мироустроительная борьба»  - это «задуманная  мироустроительная борьба».

3) В принципе мы имеем соединение двух пар разных по теме прилагательных, которые не хотелось бы выстраивать в один ряд, да  и  структура предложения   «читается» в том случае, если прилагательные  каким-либо образом разделить.

4) При решении задачи прилагательные можно сблизить по значению или использовать сложные прилагательные (предлагается в качестве возможных вариантов):

(1) « Поэтому энергетические войны следует рассматривать в контексте глобально-исторической проектной мироустроительной борьбы  между противодействующими социальными субъектами».

(2) « Поэтому энергетические войны следует рассматривать в контексте глобальной, исторической,  проектно-мироустроительной борьбы  между противодействующими социальными субъектами».

Comment: Не очень понимаю принципы постановки запятых... Т.е. вы все объединили под определением "глобальной"? Мне кажется, тут или вообще не нужны запятые или нужны везде.

Comment: Не может стоять столько неоднородных определений подряд. Поэтому где-то запятые нужны. Учитывая общую туманность фразы, София предложила меньшее из зол. Соглашайтесь! ))

Comment: Здесь как бы три однородных определения. "Глобальной исторической" - первое определение состоит из дух неоднородных определений с семантикой "всемирный исторический, всемирно исторический".

Comment: Дело не только в семантике отдельных определений, но и  в их конкретном значении в данном тексте. Автор может считать их неоднородными, может сблизить значения при раскрытии определенной темы, в том числе попарно. Но все решения должны соответствовать читаемой структуре предложения, а варианты "все однородные" и "все неоднородные" не читаются.